# Why Define Holomorphic Functions Only on Open Regions?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I recently started learning complex analysis and I'm curious as to why, by definition, only functions defined on open sets $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ can be holomorphic. I see no issue with defining the derivative on boundary points of an arbitrary set $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$; the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}$$is still something we can analyze when $z \in \partial A$. So why cut these functions out of the definition? Certainly openness of the domain will come in handy when proving theorems about holomorphic functions, but is that the only reason we ignore the non-open case? Or does the definition itself not carry over, contrary to what I suggested?

Comment: For example, holomorphic implies infinitely differentiable.  But complex differentiable at a point does not.  Sometimes we do talk about a function holomorphic on an open set and continuous on the boundary of the set.  As with many definitions: it has come to be defined this way because that is the useful definition.

Comment: For example one can have functions on the closed unit disc for which  the above exists everywhere  on the closed unit disc but they are not holomorphic at any point on the unit circle in the sense that there is no open disc centered at any boundary point and a holomorphic function there coinciding with the given one on the intersection of that with the unit disc, so  it would  very confusing to call such holomorphic  at circle points